# How to get the absolute path of a file in a Symfony2 controller?

Tags: symfony

I want to send an email with an attachement so therefore I need the absolute path to the pdf file.

I tried the flowing code in the controller:

```
$this->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('MyDoc.pdf', 'doc');
```

But this returns:

```
/bundles/MyBundle/doc/MyDoc.pdf?v=1
```

This is the path without the domain for web access. But I need the real path starting the root of the disk, like example below. How is this possible? Thanks.

```
/home/MyAccount/public_html/web/src/company/MyBundle/Resources/public/doc/MyDoc.pdf
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$this->get('templating.helper.assets')` asset helper is about **HTTP URI**, not directory path.
However, you can easily get the right absolute directory web path like this:

```
$appPath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');
$webPath = realpath($appPath . '/../web');
```

`$webPath` should return something like this:

```
/home/martins/www/symfony-project/web
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit of a cheat sheet for anyone else looking for different URL/URI paths for different applications.

Using the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` component, there are lots of different ways you can call upon this.

Consider this link `http://dev.col.com/app_dev.php/my-route?bar=1&foo=bar`

```
$r = $this->getRequest();
$r->getClientIp()                   127.0.0.1
$r->getScriptName()                 /app_dev.php
$r->getPathInfo()                   /my-route
$r->getBasePath()                   ''
$r->getBaseUrl()                    /app_dev.php
$r->getScheme()                     http
$r->getPort()                       80
$r->getHttpHost()                   dev.col.com
$r->getRequestUri()                 /app_dev.php/my-route?bar=1&foo=bar
$r->getBaseServerUrl()              http://dev.col.com
$r->getUri()                        http://dev.col.com/app_dev.php/my-route?bar=1&foo=bar
$r->getUriForPath("/other-path")    http://dev.col.com/app_dev.php/other-path
$r->getQueryString()                bar=1&foo=bar
$r->isSecure()                      false
$r->getHost()                       dev.col.com
$r->getMethod()                     GET
$r->isXmlHttpRequest()              false
```

---

Or you can do it in Twig as well.  For example:

```
<div>
    <a href="{{ job.url }}">
        <img src="{{ app.request.scheme ~ '://' ~ app.request.host }}{{ asset(job.webPath) }}" alt="{{ job.company }} logo" />
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="{{ job.url }}">
        <img src="{{ app.baseServerUrl }}{{ asset(job.webPath) }}"alt="{{ job.company }} logo" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->in("dir")->name("name.file");

foreach ($finder as $file) {
    // Dump the absolute path
    var_dump($file->getRealPath());
}
```

From Docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html